# C Cache Simulator Initialization issue

Tags: c, caching, memory, simulator, allocation

I have to program a cache simulator in C for my computer architecture class. I have no problems with what is required of me and my program is nearly finished, however I am having an issue with my CreateCache method. For some reason AFTER I create my cache, when I then go to insert a single address to the cache via index and tag, each set/block in the cache is identical. If I add one entry to a the 1st set in a 4 set cache, all 4 sets will then have that same tag. My cache needs to be able to support associative (n-ways) and direct, and also must include L1 L2 and L3 memory.

If anyone could please take a look at my method and struct and tell me if there are any apparent errors I would greatly appreciate it. I have been stuck on this for days and the assignment is due tomorrow. Thank you all in advance!!

Here is the structs I am using, as well as the createCache method.

```
    typedef struct block {
    unsigned long tag;
    int valid; //0 for invalid, 1 valid
}block;

typedef struct set {
    int numBlocks;
    block *blks;
    int alg;
}set;


typedef struct Cache{
    int FIFO, LRU; //index for alg
    int hits, misses, reads, writes;
    unsigned long accesses;
    int cacheSize;
    int numSets;
    int numBlocks; //total blocks
    set *sets;
    int blockSize;
    int assoc;  //number of lines each in set
    int alg;
}Cache;
```

And here is the createCache method I am using. I think the error lies in how I used pointers and set up the arrays of sets and blocks.

```
Cache createCache(int cacheSize, int blockSize, int alg, int assoc){
    if(cacheSize<=0 || blockSize <=0 || (alg!=0 && alg!=1)){
        perror("Invalid input!");
        exit;
    }
    Cache *new = (Cache*)malloc(sizeof(Cache));
    //initialize all values
    new->hits=0;
    new->misses=0;
    new->reads=0;
    new->writes=0;
    new->alg=alg;
    new->assoc = assoc;
    new->cacheSize=cacheSize;
    new->blockSize=blockSize;
    new->numBlocks=(int)(cacheSize/blockSize);
    new->numSets=(int)(new->numBlocks/assoc);
   // new->set->blk = (block*)malloc(sizeof(block)* new->numSets);
        //creates array with n sets
    if(assoc >= 1){
            set *s = malloc(sizeof(set));
            block *b = malloc(sizeof(block));
            new->sets = s;
            new->sets->blks = b;

            //for each set
            for(int x=0; x < new->numSets; x++){
                new->sets[x] = *s;
                new->sets[x].alg=alg;
                new->sets[x].numBlocks = new->numBlocks;
              //  new->sets[x] = (set*)malloc(sizeof((set* new->numLines);
                for(int y=0; y < assoc; y++){
                    //add for blks[y]
                    new->sets[x].blks[y] = *b;
                    new->sets[x].blks[y].valid = -1;
                    new->sets[x].blks[y].tag = NULL;  //null?
                }
            }
        }//end if
    return *new;
}
```

To make it easier to visualize, this is what happens when I print my cache. For this example I made a direct cache and added a single address to the cache.

```
Set 0
 Block 0
 tag 0
Set 1
 Block 0
 tag 0
Set 2
 Block 0
 tag 0
Set 3
 Block 0
 tag 0


Adding address:  7fff006891a8


Set 0
 Block 0
 tag 7fff006891a
Set 1
 Block 0
 tag 7fff006891a
Set 2
 Block 0
 tag 7fff006891a
Set 3
 Block 0
 tag 7fff006891a
```

Comment: What did you discover when you ran this in a debugger?

Comment: Everything functions properly without errors when I debug. However when I add an address into a single block within a set, for some reason every set/block then has the same tag assigned to it. It's as if each additional set/block is just a pointer to the first. I've tried everything to try and fix it but I am lost.

Comment: 1) `block *b = malloc(sizeof(block));` 1a) `new->sets->blks = b;` you are allocating 1 block here 2) `new->sets[x].blks[y] = *b;` you are adressing it upto assoc members here. BTW: **don't cast malloc()s return value**

Comment: Is that where the issue lies? Im not sure how i'd correct it as I've tried everything I can think of.

Ultimately, I need an array of sets, with each set having an array of blocks equal to the number of the assoc.

Comment: `block *b = malloc(assoc * sizeof *b);`

Comment: Okay I see how that could be a potential problem. However, even after changing that I am still having the same problem and all sets are still identical, regardless of whether or not I add something to them.

Comment: ... and the same for sets: `set *s = malloc(new->numSets * sizeof *s);`

Comment: I did that already as well, but to no avail. Is there something i'm doing wrong within my for loops where I assign the value of new->sets[x] = *s?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something i'm doing wrong within my for loops where I assign
>   the value of new->sets[x] = *s?

Quasi… Since you set `new->sets = s`, for *x = 0* the `new->sets[x] = *s` is equivalent to `*s = *s`.
The main error is that you set the `blks` pointer of all `new->sets` to one and the same `block *b` (by copying `*s` to each `new->sets[x]` for *x = 0* to *numSets-1*). A proper initialization would be:

```
    if (assoc >= 1)
    {
            set *s = malloc(new->numSets * sizeof(set));
            new->sets = s;
            for (int x=0; x < new->numSets; x++)
            {   // for each set
                new->sets[x].blks = malloc(assoc * sizeof(block));
                new->sets[x].alg = alg;
                new->sets[x].numBlocks = assoc;
                for (int y=0; y < assoc; y++)
                {
                    new->sets[x].blks[y].valid = -1;
                    new->sets[x].blks[y].tag = NULL;
                }
            }
    }
```